# Nodejs CLI application with UI

Tags: javascript, node.js, user-interface, window, command-line-interface

I want to run a NodeJS command line application with a small window.
It should be possible to defined a form in this window and process the input data.

Can you recommend a npm? I thought there is one which opens a light version of a browser window and you could implement functions for form tags. So I could defined a HTML form and work with it. But I can't find it anymore.

I don't want to open a browser with cmd() because it's just a configuration window and a web server is not needed.

Answer (score -2):

First of all a CLI application with a GUI is called a desktop application.
if you want to develop desktop GUI applications using NodeJS you can use Electron, in fact many of the applications you might be using regularly are built with Electron like Skype, VScode,...etc

PS: you should do more research before you ask a question on SO

Comment: This is a valid question. You have environments where you can't run an GUI with electron like on servers. Good example for CLI with some kind of UI is k9s.

Comment: Please read the question again, also OP said "I thought there is one which opens a light version of a browser" which is electron.